# Symfony mailer raw content is weird, contains =20 =3D =

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm using [symfony mailer component](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/mailer.html) and making the HTML template with twig.

After sending email in symfony profiler email section, the raw content is something I can't understand!

**What are those? do they affect the spamminess level?**

[image]

And this is my code:

```
$email = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from(new Address($this->container->getParameter('mailer_no_replay'), 'B2B Marketing'))//TODO: Translation
            ->to(new Address($lead->getEmail(), $lead->getName()))
            ->subject($emailTemplate->getSubject())
            ->htmlTemplate('emails/email-messages/crm-email.html.twig')
            ->context([
                'user' => $lead,
                'content' => $mailContent,
            ]);
        $this->mailer->send($email);
```

And the templates:

1: child (extends 2)

```
{% extends 'emails/content-email.html.twig' %}
{% block emailMessage %}
    {{ content | raw}}
{% endblock %}
```

2: parent

```
{% extends 'emails/emailBase.html.twig' %}
{#
This Template used for rendering emails that just have a content not need to render anything else
#}
{% block content %}
    <div style="background-color:#ffffff;">
        <div class="block-grid"
             style="Margin: 0 auto; min-width: 320px; max-width: 790px; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; background-color: #e8f5f8;">
            <div style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;background-color:#e8f5f8;">
                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
                       style="background-color:#ffffff;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:790px">
                                <tr class="layout-full-width" style="background-color:#e8f5f8"><![endif]-->
                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
                <td align="center" width="790"
                    style="background-color:#e8f5f8;width:790px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;"
                    valign="top">
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-right: 25px; padding-left: 25px; padding-top:60px; padding-bottom:60px;">
                <![endif]-->
                <div class="col num12"
                     style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 790px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 790px;">
                    <div style="width:100% !important;">
                        <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
                        <div
                            style="border-top:0px solid transparent; border-left:0px solid transparent; border-bottom:0px solid transparent; border-right:0px solid transparent; padding-top:60px; padding-bottom:60px; padding-right: 25px; padding-left: 25px;">
                            <!--<![endif]-->
                            <!--[if mso]>
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif">
                            <![endif]-->
                            <div
                                style="color:#34495e;font-family:Open Sans, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:1.5;padding-right:20px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:20px;">
                                <div
                                    style="line-height: 1.5; font-size: 13px; color: #34495e; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 18px;">
                                    {% block emailMessage %}{% endblock %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--<![endif]-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: That's completely normal mime [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding.

Comment: @msg yeah now I know, I told in the question if you can help, but I think you pointed me negatively, thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, that was me, I don't find it particularly useful or well researched (that's the purpose of votes) since searching "email =20" returns three relevant questions in the first page. If it worries you that much you can always delete the question now that you have an answer.

Comment: @msg I have respect for you because you helped me :), but honestly searching "email =20" returns "20 minute mail - Temporary E-Mail 10 Minute and more" or another irrelevant result, Anyway I won't remove this question, because it can other people, Thanks again ;)

Comment: ... because it can help other people

Comment: I meant search in SO not in google but yeah, happy to have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These characters are:

**Quoted-Printable, or QP encoding**, is a binary-to-text encoding system using printable ASCII characters.
QP works by using the equals sign = as an escape character.

**Example**:
The following example is a French text (encoded in UTF-8), with a high frequency of letters with diacritical marks (such as the é).

```
J'interdis aux marchands de vanter trop leurs marchandises. Car ils se font=
vite p=C3=A9dagogues et t'enseignent comme but ce qui n'est par essence qu=
'un moyen, et te trompant ainsi sur la route =C3=A0 suivre les voil=C3=
=A0 bient=C3=B4t qui te d=C3=A9gradent, car si leur musique est vulgaire il=
s te fabriquent pour te la vendre une =C3=A2me vulgaire.
   =E2=80=94=E2=80=89Antoine de Saint-Exup=C3=A9ry, Citadelle (1948)
```

**This encodes the following quotation:**

> J'interdis aux marchands de vanter trop leurs marchandises. Car ils se font vite pédagogues et t'enseignent comme but ce qui n'est par essence qu'un moyen, et te trompant ainsi sur la route à suivre les voilà bientôt qui te dégradent, car si leur musique est vulgaire ils te fabriquent pour te la vendre une âme vulgaire.
>
> — Antoine de Saint-Exupéry, Citadelle (1948)

More details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

Thanks to msg.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please, [see code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144681/create-class-with-dynamic-name-and-properties-vanilla-js/72147187#72147187)